# Return volume name in Do loop

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm trying to create a script for HP UFT to automatically create/mount/unmount VHDs as needed. The problem is that `diskpart` takes quite a while to create, mount, format and label the VHD. I need a method to pause the script while the VHD is being created/mounted, after which it will continue on with the script.

The variable `uftDrive` is currently returning a drive letter, not a volume name, so the loop just runs indefinitely. Any thoughts as to how to pass the volume names as a variable? The VHD script is automatically assigning the first-available drive letter to the drive, as we have multiple machines that UFT will be run on, and they don't have identical network drive mappings, forcing us to dynamically detect the drive by volume name.

```
'===========================================================================
'This will check to see if the Virtual Hard Disk (VHD) exists, and if not,
'create it
'===========================================================================
Dim makevhdExists, vhdExists
Set makevhdExists = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set vhdExists = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not makevhdExists.FileExists("c:\UFT\mountVHD.bat") Then
    makevhdExists.CopyFile "\\companyADfolders\Users\UFT\VHD\*.*", "c:\UFT\"
End If
If Not makevhdExists.FileExists("c:\UFT\unmountVHD.bat") Then
    wait 2
    ElseIf Not vhdExists.FileExists("C:\UFT\UFT.vhd") Then
    SystemUtil.Run "cmd","/c""C:\UFT\createVHD.bat"""
End If

Dim uftExists, uftDrive
uftExists = "False"
Do
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where VolumeName = 'UFT'")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        uftDrive = objItem.Name 'This is currently returning a drive letter,
                                'not a volume name
        If uftDrive.Name = "UFT" Then 
            uftExists = "True"**
        End If
    Next
Loop Until uftExists = "True"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the wait part

```
WScript.Sleep 5000
```

where the value indicated is milliseconds

For the second part, maybe i'm missing something, so, instead of an answer I have one silly question:

If you query `wmi` for `win32_logicaldisk` instances where their `VolumeName` is `UFT`, WHY your `if` command checks the `Name` property instead of the `VolumeName` property?

In any case, you don't need that `if`. If `colItems.Count` is greater than 0, there is at least one instance that matches the indicated condition

Something like this should work

```
Dim uftExists
uftExists = False

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Do
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where VolumeName = 'UFT'")
    If colItems.Count > 0 Then 
        utfExists = True
    Else 
        Sleep 500
    End If
Loop Until uftExists
```

Comment: I've hacked up the contents of the Do Loop so much that I think I've checked every property possible. This just happens to be what it looks like in its current iteration.

I'd considered using WScript.Sleep, but I think I'd prefer it to pause only until the UFT drive is located, hence the Do Loop. I have more lines further down the script that I plan to implement the Do Loop again for other purposes.

Comment: Worked! Thanks! I changed to uftDrive.Name to uftDrive.VolumeName and it detected it. Woohoo!

Comment: @Kjones, the best approach should be `do / check and exit on sucess / sleep 500 / loop`. This will require less cpu. Answer updated

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: To delay the script, you can use this function:

```vbs
WScript.Sleep 1000
```

The number is in Milliseconds, so 1000 is 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Changing ObjItem.Name to ObjItem.VolumeName worked!

```
For Each objItem in colItems
    uftDrive = objItem.VolumeName 'This is currently returning a drive letter, not a volume name
    If uftDrive = "UFT" Then 
        uftExists = "True"**
    End If
Next
```